# RegEx validation inTextEdit control of DevExpress

Tags: devexpress-wpf

I need to restrict user input in a text edit control  to 1-99. After reading this ticket https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q458791, used a RegEx mask to achieve it.

```
<dxe:TextEdit Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding FontSize , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" MaskType="RegEx" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" Mask="^[1-9]\d?$" EditValueChanged="TextEdit_EditValueChanged"/>
```

Now its showing the mask string as well in the input area (^[1-9]\d?$). Tried with **different reg ex combinations**. Please help.

Comment: Don't use the mask as display format. You don't convert or change the format.

Comment: No luck , :( . If I type 10 it will show ^10$

Comment: Ups, my fault! Remove the ^ and $. You won't need that. I'll explain that ASAP as answer :)

Comment: it worked.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` and `$` usually marks the beginning and the end of a string in a regex filtered mask. In these text editors, the input is always counted as a string. You don't need to do this by yourself.

If you would search in a text for a specific combination, you will need to use `^` and `$`.